# "Recasting" a subclass instance (declared as base class) to an interface - why does it work?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I want to have subclasses that implement arbitrary interfaces, but are declared as a base class, so that the application would try to "recast" the instances to that interface and use them if recast is successful.

I had some doubts and so I made this short spike and, both for my joy and surprise, it works.

My question is: Why and how does it work? Is there a formal way that I could have known it would work beforehand? Some sort of "casting rules" in C#?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new SubClass() as BaseClass;

        Console.WriteLine(obj is ISubClass); // output = "True"

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class BaseClass { }

class SubClass : BaseClass, ISubClass { }

interface ISubClass { }
```

Comment: No, `obj` is actually a `SubClass` which does implement `ISubClass`.

Comment: I think the thing you need to understand is that casting does not change the type of the object for reference types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an instance of `SubClass` and `SubClass` is inheriting from both the interface and `BaseClass`, so we can cast the reference of the object `SubClass` to either of those. The actual type still remains `SubClass`, you have just casted the reference to it's base type, if you check by calling `GetType()` on the instance you will see that it will evaluate to type `SubClass`, so it is just reference conversion, the original object still is same.

You might want to read about [polymorphsim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Reference Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711612%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

(edit by OP) From second link:

> Conversions from a base type to a derived type only succeed at run time if the value being converted is a null reference or a reference type that is either the derived type itself or a more derived type.
>
> (...) a class type can always be cast to an interface type that it implements. Similarly, conversions from an interface type to a class type that implements it only succeed at run time if the value being converted is a null reference or a reference type that is either the class type itself or a type derived from the class type.

Comment: Is "reference conversion" a well-established concept? Where could I learn more about it?

Comment: The "Reference Conversion" link settles the question, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The object is still of type `SubClass` you only use as reference the type of `BaseClass`. And because it is of type `SubClass` it also does implement the `ISubClass` interface. A cast does not update the origin object, it does only "change the reference" to the object.

Like you show in your code, with simple changes:

1. you create a `SubClass` object: `SubClass obj = new SubClass();`
2. now you cast it: `BaseClass bObj = obj as BaseClass;` but the original object is still of type `SubClass`. You could also do this `ISubClass sObj = obj as ISubClass;` and `ISubClass sObj = bObj as ISubClass` because you work always on the origin object.

Another example is polymorphism. The whole concept would not work, when the origin object would be changed when casting.

- As general hint, you do not need the explicite cast to `var obj = new SubClass() as BaseClass;`, this would also work: `BaseClass obj = new SubClass();`

Comment: Hmm... Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, you won't be able to call methods of SubClass (even if the methods are declared in ISublass), but at runtime, if you make that check, it will return true.

Comment: "at runtime, if you make that check, it will return true." Could you elaborate more on that? And also, do you think this is an acceptable design for "sort-of" polymorphism?

Answer (score 1):

When you cast to the parent class you are limited to only using those methods and properties available to any object that inherits from the parent class.  The object is still of the type you created with the `new` statement, `SubClass`.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseProp { get; set; }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass, ISubClass
{
    public int ChildProp { get; set; }
}

interface ISubClass
{
    int ChildProp { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new SubClass() as BaseClass;

        // obj IS SubClass type, but we are only going to use properties and methods
        // available to ANY BaseClass

        obj.BaseProp = 1;  // this is fine
        obj.ChildProp = 2;  // this doesn't work (BaseClass does not contain a definition for ChildProp)

        (obj as SubClass).ChildProp = 2;  // this works
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use "as" keyword, it does not create a new instance of BaseClass. The instance still remains of SubClass.

If you have created a new instance of BaseClass from SubClass instance it would have displayed false as you expected.